# sendform and some data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-post

I need to send to server form data and some array. I'm trying to do next:

```
var array= [3,4,5,1,2]
var form = $(this);
var url = $(this).attr("action");
And $.post(url, {form: form, array:array})
```

But it's not sending.

Comment: Ajax post syntax is `$.post( url, [data], [callback], [type] )`

Comment: `$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );` taken from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this:

```
var array= [3,4,5,1,2];
data={
    form:$(this).serialize(),
    array:array
};

$.ajax({
    url:$(this).attr("action");
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    success:function(data){
       //Success process
    },
    error:function(data){
       //Error process     
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send form data by using serialize method

try this-

```
var array= [3,4,5,1,2]
var form = $(this).serialize();
var url = $(this).attr("action");
$.post(url, {form: form, array:array},function(result){
    $("span").html(result);
});
```

data in ajax post is send like this-

```
{ key1 : value1 , key2 : value2 }
```